# How to know for sure which keywoard layout is active while entering passphrase for decrypting disk at startup on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, decryption

I have installed a brand new Ubuntu 18.04 distribution on my laptop and i chose to encrypt the disk.
During the installation, i used a french layout (AZERTY) as i have a french keyboard. But now that i have restarted the laptop, it seems that the active layout is not a french one.
Is there a way to confirm which layout is active?
If i boot to command line from Grub, it is definitely a QWERTY layout? 
But is it the same used when entering the passphrase?